# Displaying a balloon when user hovers over an object

Tags: jquery, css, balloon

I am designing a blog theme. I am trying to make an info balloon that will appear when user hovers on author's name, similar to Facebook balloons when we hover on names a balloon appear and when the cursor leave name or balloon it fades Out.

like this 
dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28793409/baloon.jpg

I've tried some Jquery but always had problem because I want that when user is on balloon that not be hidden. i know my jquery code is a disaster :D

```
$(function() {          
var authorInfo = $('.author-info');

$('.author').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.author-info').delay(700).fadeIn();
});


$('.author-info').mouseleave(function(){
    authorInfo.fadeOut();
});

$('.close').hover(function(){
    authorInfo.fadeOut();
});

$('.close').hover(function(){
    authorInfo.fadeOut();
});

$('#sereen').hover(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});

authorInfo.hover(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
});

});
```

and this is the balloon i designed
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28793409/Capture.JPG

its the page http://bit.ly/1uKDY3V
, please hover on author name on posts.  i did the HTML and CSS part but i am not good at Jquery and JS so please help me to make it.

Comment: I don't understand. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Are you trying to make a tooltip? There are lots of tutorials for doing tooltips in JQuery

Comment: yes i am  trying to make a tooltip. but my tooltip is a little diffrent

Comment: Your balloon on web site seems to work fine with my Opera 12...nothing strange...what is your problem?